# When is it better to use a variable rather than a graph node to store intermediate results in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any advantage in storing tensors in variables rather than relying on nodes in the graph, other than that variables persist over multiple runs of the graph and can be shared? Is resource management perhaps better supported for variables vs graph nodes?

Comment: You mean tf.constant node? It's probably better to use variable from performance aspect. Constant node puts data in graphdef which wasn't designed for large sizes. There's 2gb hard limit. Also when graphdef needs to be serialized (ie for distributed tf), this constant node will go through protobuf serialization which could be inefficient

Comment: Not necessarily a constant node. Say for example I want to store the forward activations for each layer of an MLP, then I would accumulate the activations in a list `a.append(tf.matmul(a[-1], W) + b)` and later access them via `a[l]`. Would it here be beneficial to store each activation tensor in a variable instead?

Comment: `a.append(..)` doesn't actually store any activation values, you have to do `sess.run(a[l])` to get them, which will do the same computation as `sess.run(tf.matmul(a[-1], W) + b)`

Comment: I am aware of that. What I have in mind is accessing the `a[l]` much later in the same graph, and my question is whether variables would be preferable over very long vertices in the graph ('long' if one were to plot the graph it against time).

Comment: If all computation is done in a single `.run` call, doing all computations without variables is typical. This way potentially gives more opportunities for optimization on the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*From @YaroslavBulatov:*)

If you need to store tensors at the beginning of your graph to reuse later:

```
        x
        |            
      conv1   ------        
        |           | 
      conv2         |  
        |           |
      conv3         |  
        |          loooong dependency
       ...          | 
        |           |
     deconv1        |
        |           |
        +   --------
        |
       res
```

Here you compute `conv1` at the beginning, and reuse it much later in the graph when computing `res`.

---

The best way to do that is in fact to **do nothing** and let TensorFlow handle that long term dependency.

When calling `sess.run(res, feed_dict={x: ...})`, TensorFlow will compute the different layers `conv1`, `conv2`, ..., and store the ones necessary to compute `res`later one (here `conv1`).

I believe this is the same mechanism as with the backward propagation, where TensorFlow needs to keep in memory the activations to compute the gradients later on.